# intersection of shapes in OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, numpy

I have a program that detects contours of different shapes in an image with the help of `cv2.findContours` function. I need to merge all the contours that are inside or partly inside (i.e. those that only intersect) the rotated rectangle, which is given by four edge points.

Right now my program looks at every contour and sees if any point of this contour is situated between the four lines, which are defined by the rectangle's edge points. It works more or less, but it is quite slow and I see sometimes errors I can't explain, so that's why I'd like to use any other available method, if it is available. Thank you in advance

Upd:
[example of the processed frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VC1s.png)

I have track detection in the cloud chamber, and one of the biggest problems is that the program can't see if separate contours are parts of the same track, or, maybe, it is they are just different tracks

Comment: When you say 'shape', do you mean a solid shape? Or just the contour of the shape? For example, if the rotated rectangle is entirely inside the contour, do you call them 'intersect'?

Comment: Show us a sample input image. Also show us the code that you have done so far.

Comment: This is the contour of the shape, the rectangle is calculated with the help of this:

rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)

I then make the rectangle wider and see if it intersects any other shapes. If there are any intersections, then I see, if the angle of the rectangle of the found shape is similar with some error to the angle of the first rectangle, and if it is, then I merge them together.

Comment: @Titanoboa   
I don't know, what you exactly want -- I have more than 300 lines of code for the whole program. But if you want to see everything, I can send it somewhere. But still the existing code for the algorithm described above is a real pain in the neck with many "if" statements and auxiliary variables

Comment: @Oresto thats fine. Can you post the original input image here (without any post processing i.e the blue box and the processed text) so that I could try some stuff. High quality image would be preferred.

Comment: @Titanoboa What do you mean by the blue box and the processed text? xD I have an input video, and I am subtracting background to see the tracks. Anyway, I'm giving you the link to the [files I have](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2ir4GCgnr9LR1licy1Sd0tna0E). The video.py is the main body file and in two other files are the functions (I don't use all of them). This algorithm with merging (called mergerect) is in the track.py

Comment: @Titanoboa The function "merge" in "track.py" I don't currently use, but I was thinking of merging firstly little tracks (with the surrounding rectangles' perimeters smaller than specific perimeter) that are close enough to each other and then applying "mergerect".

 Also this "mergerect" automatically adds to the chosen contour those shapes that are inside the extended rectangle but have perimeter smaller then the "filterper" value

Comment: Ran the program and found out that there are like huge time issues with your code in the `inrectangle` function and `mergerect` function. More specifically the `right`,`left` functions (made 23 million calls in 40 mins for processing 30 frames)  are taking too much time. More details [click here](http://imgur.com/a/bsoyW) .  Suggest you ignore some contours. I would like to try myself to improve but I would like to know what precise region of interest are you trying to obtain (like the conditions).

Comment: @Titanoboa I have to count tracks and calculate their area. This cloud chamber should calculate the sample's activity and emitted particles' energies (this will be possible by knowing the area of the tracks). And also the program should see every track's velocity vector, but this is the other issue.

Comment: @Titanoboa Also, the runtime is not so important -- the main task for program is to run correctly:)

Comment: @Titanoboa Are you still here?

Comment: @Oresto yes I am here, sorry about the late reply, just busy with work. Here's an idea that I wanted to try out but I didn't have the time. Since your camera is very stable, you could just compare the frames by taking one image that doesn't have any of the tracks, and compare it with the other frames to detect the tracks using `cv2.absdiff` and then use contour properties to determine whether the tracks are joined. I'll try this out when I have the time and get back to you soon :)